# How to fix "incompatible pointer type" error in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have homework about function pointers and implement inheritance in C. I got "incompatible pointer type" error about Aralik, VerilenlerArasindan and Harfler. What's problem?

> RastgeleKarakter.h

```
    struct RASTGELEKARAKTER{
        Random ran;
        char (*Harf)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
        char* (*Harfler)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
        char* (*Aralik)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
        char* (*VerilenlerArasindan)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
        char* (*Cumle)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
        void (*YokEt)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
    };

    typedef struct RASTGELEKARAKTER* RastgeleKarakter;

    RastgeleKarakter RastegeleKarakterOlustur();
    char RandomHarf(RastgeleKarakter);
    char* RandomHarfler(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned);
    char* RandomAralik(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned,char,char);
    char* RandomVerilenlerArasindan(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned,char*);
    char* RandomCumle(RastgeleKarakter);
    void RastgeleKarakterYokEt(RastgeleKarakter);
```

> RastgeleKarakter.c

```
RastgeleKarakter RastegeleKarakterOlustur(){

    RastgeleKarakter karakter;
    karakter = (RastgeleKarakter)malloc(sizeof(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER));
    karakter->ran = RandomOlustur();
    karakter->Harf = &RandomHarf;
    karakter->Harfler = &RandomHarfler;
    karakter->Aralik = &RandomAralik;
    karakter->VerilenlerArasindan = &RandomVerilenlerArasindan;
    karakter->Cumle = &RandomCumle;
    karakter->YokEt = &RastgeleKarakterYokEt;
    return karakter;
}
```

Comment: Some of your functions take more arguments than the single `RASTGELEKARAKTER*`. The structure members are not defined that way though.

Comment: And an unrelated side-note: While the Windows API is full of them, using type-aliases of pointers (like you create for `RastgeleKarakter`) is usually a bad idea. It makes the code harder to understand, and therefore harder to maintain. And it's all to easy to forget that the type-alias is a pointer and accidentally use `RastgeleKarakter*` somewhere where it's not supposed to be.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>       karakter->Harfler = &RandomHarfler;

because

> char* (*Harfler)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);

but

> char* RandomHarfler(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned);

*RandomHarfler* gets two argument but *Harfler* must receive a pointer to a function getting only a `struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*`

---

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>       karakter->Aralik = &RandomAralik;

because

> char* (*Aralik)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);

but

> char* RandomAralik(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned,char,char);

*RandomAralik* gets 4 arguments but *Aralik* must receive a pointer to a function getting only a `struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*`

---

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>       karakter->VerilenlerArasindan = &RandomVerilenlerArasindan;

because

> char* (*VerilenlerArasindan)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);

but

> char* RandomVerilenlerArasindan(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned,char*);

*RandomVerilenlerArasindan* gets 3 arguments but *VerilenlerArasindan* must receive a pointer to a function getting only a `struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*`

Answer (score 2):

The `Harfler` member is declared to be a pointer to a function that takes a `struct RASTGELEKARAKTER *`:

```
char* (*Harfler)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
```

but you attempt to assign to it a pointer to RandomHarf:

```
karakter->Harf = &RandomHarf;
```

which is declared to be a pointer to a function that takes a `struct RASTGELEKARKTER *` (via the `typedef` `RastgeleKarakter`) and an `unsigned`:

```
char* RandomHarfler(RastgeleKarakter,unsigned);
```

A pointer to a function that takes one parameter is not compatible with a pointer to a function that takes two parameters.